# color tracking using webcam feed

Tags: java, animation, processing, video-processing

I am trying to create a color tracking bird flock, using live video from my webcam. I was instructed to use a constructor to create an array of .gifs that could work independently and follow a specific color around the video. 
I did some research and this is as far as I got. Now I am getting an error that I don't really understand. For a very early dummy example of the intentions i have with the code, please see this .gif: [Flock of birds](https://i.gyazo.com/16b6ddac5621891c1ee1283cac0a40f8.gif)

```
import processing.video.*;
import gifAnimation.*;
video = new Movie(); /// This is the line that gives me the error

// class
Birdy [] arrayOfBirds;
int numberOfBirds = 10;
class Birdy 
{
  //variables

  int numberOfBeaks;
  String birdName;
  color birdColor;
  PVector location;
    // constructor, allows you to make new Birds in the rest of the code
 // A constructor is part of the class 
  Birdy (int nob, String bname, color bColor, PVector loc) {
    numberOfBeaks = nob;
    birdName = bname;
    birdColor = bColor;
    location = loc;

  }
 //The bird appears
 void showBird() 
 {
    fill(birdColor);
    textSize(24);
    text(birdName, location.x, location.y);
    ellipse(location.x, location.y, 20, 20);
  }    
}

void setup() {

   size(640, 480);

  //fill the array Of Birds with new Birds
  arrayOfBirds = new Birdy[numberOfBirds];

  //to make 10 birds and put them in the array   
  for (int i = 0; i < numberOfBirds; i++)
  {                                           
    // each new bird needs its own set of parameters but will do this when i figure out how to work with this one first!
   arrayOfBirds[i]= new Birdy(2, "Tweety "+i, color(255-(i*25), i*25, 255), new PVector(i*40, i*40));
  }
}
void draw(int x, int y) {
 if (video.available()) {
   video.read();
   image(video, 0, 0, width, height); // Draw the webcam video onto the screen
   int colorX = 0; // X-coordinate of the closest in color video pixel
   int colorY = 0; // Y-coordinate of the closest in color video pixel
   float closestColor = 500; //we set this to be abritrarily large, once program runs, the first pixel it scans will be set to this value
   // Search for the closest in color pixel: For each row of pixels in the video image and
   // for each pixel in the yth row, compute each pixel's index in the video

     background(0);

  //show that first bird we called Tweety by calling the showBird() function on Tweety
  Tweety.showBird();

  //show all the birds in the array by calling the showBird() method on each object in the array
  for(int i = 0; i < arrayOfBirds.length; i++){
    arrayOfBirds[i].location = new PVector(x,y);
    arrayOfBirds[i].showBird();
  }

}
setup();
Gif loopingGif;
Capture video;
 size(640, 480); // Change size to 320 x 240 if too slow at 640 x 480 // Uses the default video input ---- but i dont think it works
 video = new Capture(this, width, height, 30);
 video.start();
 noStroke();
 smooth();

  frameRate(10);
    loopingGif  = new Gif(this, "circle.gif");

    String [] animas = {};

   video.loadPixels();
   int index = 0;
   for (int y = 0; y < video.height; y++) {
     for (int x = 0; x < video.width; x++) {
       // Get the color stored in the pixel
       color pixelValue = video.pixels[index];
       // Determine the color of the pixel
       float colorProximity = abs(red(pixelValue)-27)+abs(green(pixelValue)-162)+abs(blue(pixelValue)-181); //select pixel
       // If that value is closer in color value than any previous, then store the
       // color proximity of that pixel, as well as its (x,y) location
       if (colorProximity < closestColor) {
         closestColor = colorProximity;
         closestColor=closestColor-10; //Once it "locks" on to an object of color, it wont let go unless something a good bit better (closer in color) comes along
         colorY = y;
         colorX = x;
       }
       index++;
     }
     draw(x,y);
   }
   image (loopingGif, colorX, colorY);
    loopingGif.play();
}here
```

Comment: You're declaring variables (`video`, `arrayOfBirds`, `numberOfBirds`)  outside of a class. That's a syntax error.

Comment: Also, krizz: for the future, you should consider more meaningful question titles.

Comment: I really wonder how you guys start working on such advanced concepts when you don't understand the basics of a language.

Comment: @Kayman This is Processing, not Java. Processing variables do not need to be inside of a class. (More accurately, they're automatically placed into a class by the Processing compiler.)

Answer (score 0):

You need to declare your variable by giving it a **type**:

```
Movie video = new Movie();
```

You've got some other weird things going on here. Why are you specifically calling the `setup()` function? Processing does that for you automatically. You've also got a bunch of code outside of a function at the bottom of your sketch. Maybe you meant to put that code inside the `setup()` function?

If you're still getting errors, edit your question to include their exact full text.